How can I simplify two selects
Is it possible to simplify two selects, maybe into one as they add a bit of time when used in a stored Procedure and called many times?
/* Get Our OVER Spent Codes */
select SUM(Cmt.BALANCE_TD)
from CODES_MONTHLY_TABLE Cmt
WHERE (Cmt.id = :ip_id) and (Cmt.BALANCE_TD < 0) and ((Cmt.THEMONTH - 1) = :ip_currentmonth)
into :op_overspent_codes;

/* Get Our UNDER Spent Codes */
select SUM(Cmt.BALANCE_TD)
from CODES_MONTHLY_TABLE Cmt
WHERE (Cmt.id = :ip_id) and (Cmt.BALANCE_TD > 0) and ((Cmt.THEMONTH - 1) = :ip_currentmonth)
into :op_underspent_codes;

The table CODES_MONTHLY_TABLE is quite large and I have an index on the field Cmt.id.
These are input parameters:

:ip_id
:ip_currentmonth


Try
select 
  SUM(case when (Cmt.BALANCE_TD < 0) then Cmt.BALANCE_TD else 0 end) ,
  SUM(case when (Cmt.BALANCE_TD > 0) then Cmt.BALANCE_TD else 0 end)
from CODES_MONTHLY_TABLE Cmt
WHERE (Cmt.id =  :ip_id) and (Cmt.THEMONTH  = (:ip_currentmonth - 1))
INTO :op_overspent_codes,:op_underspent_codes;

And index on (id, themonth) is better for this query performance.
Upd1.  Should be
WHERE (Cmt.id =  :ip_id) and (Cmt.THEMONTH  = (:ip_currentmonth + 1))


The "Where" clause needs to be Cmt.id =  :ip_id) and ((Cmt.THEMONTH - 1) = :ip_currentmonth), I did tests with the original 2 SQL's and compared the results. The results matched only when using the "Where" above in this comment. That said with the single SQL and dual index on (id, themonth) now performs 38% quicker, so thanks.

There is typo. Should be (Cmt.THEMONTH  = (:ip_currentmonth + 1). ;))

Thanks for the update, that works. PS I have no need for the Table Alias"Cmt", so that can be removed.
